# Enable transparency in 3D - pyopengl

Tags: python, opengl, 3d, pyopengl

I have a GLViewWidget, where I add different objects (GLMeshItem) setting these properties, in order to enable transparency:

```
        opt = {
            GL_DEPTH_TEST: True,
            'glBlendFunc': (GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA),
            }
        obj.setGLOptions(opt)
```

This is almost working, in the following sense:
If I have two objects obj1 and obj2, and add them to the widget in this order, I will see obj2 in the back of obj1, but not the opposite.

I tried to add the objects in a different order, but clearly I will see obj1 behind obj2, and not the opposite. How can I make this to work for all the objects indifferently?

Comment: You will have to sort them back to front and draw them in the correct order.

Comment: But as I said both the objects are transparent, so I want them to behave in the same way, that is obj2 showing behind obj1 and obj1 showing behind obj2, depending on the point I'm watching from.

Comment: The only way (besides Order Independent Transparency) is to sort the objects in each frame according to their current position and draw them back to front.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depth testing and transparency don't work too well together.

Suppose we draw your translucent object `obj1`. This will also write it's depth to the depth buffer. 
Now suppose we want draw your second object, `obj2`, which has a greater depth. We would expect we would see `obj2` through `obj1` as `obj1` is translucent.

However, as the depth of `obj2` is greater, overlapping pixels will not be drawn as the depth test fails - so we will only see the parts of `obj2` not overlapped by `obj1`.

Depth testing does not take transparency into account. So in order to get it too work, as BDL said in the comments, you will have to manually sort the objects and draw them in the right order.

Comment: Disabling depth-testing is not necessary. Correct blending can only be achieved when the objects are drawn from back to front which means that depth-testing is not a problem any more. Even when not sorting one will have to have at least depth testing enabled and depth write disabled. Otherwise transparent objects would not be hidden by non-transparent ones.

Comment: You're right, it's not necessary to disable it. Edited it out. I meant to say that it is probably no longer necessary to have it enabled.

Comment: So supposing that I first draw obj1 at cartesian coordinates (0,0,0), then I draw obj2 at cartesian coordinates (2,0,0). If I look at the scene with the x axis pointing out the screen, I will see obj1 behind the transparent obj2, and this is correct. But if I rotate the scene, and look at it with the x axis pointing inside the screen, should I sort again the objects in order to have obj2 shown behind the transparent obj1?

Comment: Yes. `obj2` has a greater depth, so if you draw `obj1` first in the second scenario, `obj2` will not be drawn because of the depth test. I suggest you read into how depth testing works, and this might also contain useful information: https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Transparency_Sorting